# Huggingface DETR model fails with index error when trying to train on coco2017 dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to build DETR model on subset of COCO dataset using [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/detr). This is the tutorial that I am following https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/DETR/Fine_tuning_DetrForObjectDetection_on_custom_dataset_(balloon).ipynb. The tutorial loads balloon dataset, I have used COCO instead.
The code works fine up to the training part, it throws the following index error when fit is called:

### IndexError: index 64 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 3

## Stacktrace:

```
Cell In[26], line 4
      1 from pytorch_lightning import Trainer
      3 trainer = Trainer(max_steps=1, gradient_clip_val=0.1)
----> 4 trainer.fit(model)

File c:\Code\detr\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py:603, in Trainer.fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    601     raise TypeError(f"`Trainer.fit()` requires a `LightningModule`, got: {model.__class__.__qualname__}")
    602 self.strategy._lightning_module = model
--> 603 call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    604     self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    605 )

File c:\Code\detr\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\call.py:38, in _call_and_handle_interrupt(trainer, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
     36         return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
     37     else:
---> 38         return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     40 except _TunerExitException:
     41     trainer._call_teardown_hook()

File c:\Code\detr\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py:645, in Trainer._fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    638 ckpt_path = ckpt_path or self.resume_from_checkpoint
    639 self._ckpt_path = self._checkpoint_connector._set_ckpt_path(
    640     self.state.fn,
...
-> 2205 class_cost = -out_prob[:, target_ids]
   2207 # Compute the L1 cost between boxes
   2208 bbox_cost = torch.cdist(out_bbox, target_bbox, p=1)
```

There are 2 differences from the tutorial code:

1. instead of balloon, coco 2017 dataset is used
2. my machine does not have nvidia gpu, the gpu argument is not supplied to
   `trainer = Trainer(gpus=1, max_steps=300, gradient_clip_val=0.1)`

I tried debugging, and found that the code fails at following line:
`outputs = self.model(pixel_values=pixel_values, pixel_mask=pixel_mask, labels=labels)` in common_step method of Detr class.

I tried with unmodified coco2017 dataset; it always fails with the same error.
What am I missing?